# MAUI trim fails when publishing

Tags: android, maui

I have a .net maui app that uses google maps. For the map on android side I use Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps nuget. Problem is that precompiling fails for GoogleMapsUtilityBinding.dll when I'm trying to publish.

```
9>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Aot.targets(91,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\source\repos\app_with_map_repo\src\MyCompany.ThatApp.Client.Startup\obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-x86\linked\GoogleMapsUtilityBinding.dll.
9>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Aot.targets(91,5): error : Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly C:\source\repos\app_with_map_repo\src\MyCompany.ThatApp.Client.Startup\obj\Release\net6.0-android\android-x86\linked\GoogleMapsUtilityBinding.dll
9>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Aot.targets(91,5): error : AOTID DC1BE4CC-097D-2684-38D8-137DAAC52991
9>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Aot.targets(91,5): error : Using profile data file 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk\6.0.547\Sdk\maui.aotprofile'
9>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Aot.targets(91,5): error : Using profile data file 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk\6.0.547\Sdk\maui-blazor.aotprofile'
9>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Aot.targets(91,5): error : Added 0 methods from profile.
9>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Aot.targets(91,5): error : Added 0 methods from profile.
9>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Aot.targets(91,5): error : Could not load signature of Com.Google.Maps.Android.Data.Renderer:get_ImagesCache due to: Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
```

Map control is on other project file. I tried linking like that:

Map containing project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    ....
    <TrimMode>link</TrimMode>
    <PublishTrimmed>True</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootDescriptor Include="preserved_assemblies.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

preserved_assemblies.xml :

```
<linker>
  <assembly fullname="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps" preserve="all" />
</linker>
```

On main project the same, only preserved_assemblies.xml had this:

```
<linker>
  <assembly fullname="ArsIngenii.Drivers.Client.Controls" preserve="all" />
</linker>
```

Also tried to add Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat to both preserved_assemblies files. Did not work.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

It seems that I was looking at the wrong nugget. For some stuff I use Xamarin.Android.Maps.Utils (GoogleMapsUtilityBinding.dll). But situation is exactly the same. Tried same solutions. No progress.

Comment: Can the code be built successfully? Or just fail at the time of publishing?

Comment: It does compile in debug configuration. I started preparing this app for release and this started happening.

Comment: How did you prepare your app for release?  What are the specific steps?

Comment: Nothing much. Put it on Release config and then this happened. That is all. Than started to try to solve this problem. I actually solved it by using other nuget, that does not depend on  Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat,  release build worked, published it to app center, downloaded, everything worked. But still it is not completely clear how to link assemblies correctly on MAUI. On Xamarin had same problems, solved them by just adding assembly names to Link box on project properties.

Comment: I forgot that I also added a keystore and that is about it.